# Why $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x^2 + 7x)} - x$ is $7\over2$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know how to get the correct answer.

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x^2 + 7x)} - x$$
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{(x^2 + 7x) - x^2}{\sqrt{(x^2 + 7x)} + x}$$
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{7x}{\sqrt{x(x + 7)} + x}$$
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{7 \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{(x + 7)} + \sqrt{x}}$$

Now as $x \to \infty$ the value of $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x + 7)}$ becomes similar to $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{x}$

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{7 \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x}} = \frac{7}{2}$$

I want to know why this other way is incorrect :-

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x^2 + 7x)} - x$$

Now as $x \to \infty$ the value of $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x^2 + 7x)}$ becomes similar to $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{x^2}$

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x^2)} - x = 0/-2$$

Which is incorrect, i checked on a graphing calculator. But i want to know why ? please help.

Comment: @AlvinJin but i subtracted then took the limit.

Comment: When you say *similar* you should considerate that you are assuming there is a small quantity you are simplifying. Immagine it added to the similar function, in the former case it gets divided by $\sqrt{x}$ in the latter it remainder after the subtraction. That is why your second methods is wrong. If you want a better insight try searching for the small o symbol.

Comment: @N74 so if i understand properly you mean that in the former case the error left was $7$ and in latter it was $7x$ which was significant enough to produce wrong answer.

Comment: In both cases the error is a quantity $q=f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty } {q \over x}=0$. In the first evaluation you are effectively exploiting this property by dividing both numerator and denominator by $x$. In the second evaluation you remain with $\lim_{x \to \infty } q$ and you don't know what this limit evaluates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think students often think that limits are an approximate tool and when dealing with limits we can replace $A$ by $B$ even when $A \neq B$. *Sorry!!! This is never the case in mathematics.* You can replace $A$ by $B$ only when $A = B$.

Thus in your first approach when you reach the fraction $$\frac{7\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x + 7} + \sqrt{x}}$$ then you are not allowed to replace $\sqrt{x + 7}$ by $\sqrt{x}$ by saying that *they are similar*. What you can and should do is to divide both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x} \neq 0$ to get the fraction $$\dfrac{7}{\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{7}{x}} + 1}$$ and then we can see that $7/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ so the above fraction tends to $7/(\sqrt{1 + 0} + 1) = 7/2$.

---

You have yourself shown the danger of replacing $A$ by $B$ when *they are similar but not equal* in your second evaluation. A wrong approach may give a right answer sometimes but that does not make it a right approach.

Comment: Ok this made most sense.

Comment: I feel so happy that i made that silly mistake in the second evaluation, it made many things clear about limits, like i always that limits are approximating tools.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: you are not alone in thinking in that way about limits. Many students make such errors. I think some books and instructors are also to blame for that. Instead it is better to think about limits as well defined operation on functions which follow certain rules (rules of algebra of limits, squeeze theorem, rule of substitution etc). That should help to evaluate most of the basic limits.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Concept of limits is somewhat difficult to grasp because it is so different from algebraic operations of $+,-,\times, /$ and a full understanding is possible only when you have the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition. But a working knowledge of limits can be achieved if one knows the rules of limits (mentioned in previous comment) even without proof). You should have a look at my posts on limits starting with http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-1.html

Comment: I will surely read it because limits are giving me a very hard time, i didn't have so many doubts before in any other part of maths. Thanks.

Comment: thanks i read 1st and 2nd post. I don't know if i understood eplison, delta definition properly but i think i cleared a lot of my doubts.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: If you have some doubts left you should ask here on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

We can say that they are *almost* the same, so that in the difference the equal part cancel and what remains is exactly what in which they differ, so neglecting this part leads to an error.

Comment: Consider this example, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^2 + 5x + 9}{x^2 + 2}$$ now i can neglect $ 5x + 9$ in numerator and $2$ in denominater to get $2$ as the answer, which is correct, why ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i edited my comment please look now.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: my explanation was an intuitive one, but we should rest on theorems, and the theorem $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}(f-g)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f-\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g$ is only valid when $f$ and $g$ do not go both to the same infinite. In the same way, your limit could be written $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2(2+5/2x+9/x^2)}{x^2(1+2/x^2)}$ and the two parentheses have finite and not null limits and can be readily substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form it's not equal to $0$ so to get some finite value we multiply by conjugate

Comment: Could also be $0$, one cannot know in advance.

Comment: No but the point is that I am not equaling the two so the answer becomes $\infty-\infty$ Which is surely an indeterminate form

Comment: But i subtracted then took the limit, like $$\lim_{x \to a} (x - x) =  \lim_{x \to a} (0) = 0$$

Comment: The dx part by which they differ makes the difference in answer so we don't use such assumptions in limits

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^2 + 5x + 9}{x^2 + 2}$$ = $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^2}{x^2}$$ = $$2$$ and why isn't $5x + 9$ and $2$ makes a difference.

Comment: See when both numerator ,denominator approach infinity they certainly get a finite a value after manipulations here taking out $x^2$ makes it easy but not so with you example so we make both approach infinity by rationalizing and then cancel out the term which is creating a trouble so we convert $\infty-\infty$ to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:x \mapsto \sqrt x$ and $g: x \mapsto x^2+7x$.

So you noticed that $g \sim (x\mapsto x^2)$ and then you concluded from that that $f\circ g \sim (x \mapsto f(x^2))$. Be this equivalence relation is generally not compatible with composition, hence the wrong result.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what  $f\circ g \sim (x \mapsto f(x^2))$  means.

Comment: $a \sim b$ if $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=1$, and you thought that  $g \sim (x\mapsto x^2) \equiv lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)}{x^2}=1$ implied that $f\circ g \sim (x \mapsto f(x^2))\equiv lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(g(x))}{f(x^2)}=1$.

Comment: Sorry what i meant was that i didn't understand what that small circle mean ?

Comment: Oh it is the operator for the composition of two functions : $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$

Answer (score 0):

In the second way, you are making a mistake writing

> the value of $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{(x + 7)}$    becomes similar to $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{x}$

In fact, for large values of $x$,

$$\sqrt{x^2 + 7x}=x \sqrt{1+\frac 7 x}\approx x\left(1+\frac 7 {2x} \right)$$